# Various errors in C implementation of linked list

Tags: c, debugging, linked-list

Here's my code. I'm fairly sure I've implemented the Linked List correctly, but I assume there are some syntax errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct *node next;
};

void push(struct node** headRef, int data)
{
    struct node* newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = *headRef;

    *headRef = newNode;
}

struct node* primeFactors(int num)
{
    struct node* head = NULL;
    if (num == 1)
    {
        return head;
    }
    int factor = 0;
    int i = 2;
    while (i <= num)
    {
        if (num % i)
        {
            factor = i;
        }
    }
    push(&head, factor);
    primeFactors(num / factor);
    return head;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct node* head = primeFactor(600851475143);
    printf("%d/n", head->data);
}
```

Here are my errors. I have no idea what most of these mean, and struct node definitely should have a member named next.

```
    [1] $ gcc 3.c -o 3                                                                                                                 
    3.c:6:9: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘*’ token
    3.c: In function ‘push’:
    3.c:14:9: error: ‘struct node’ has no member named ‘next’
    3.c: In function ‘main’:
    3.c:42:22: warning: initialisation makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You've got your asterisk in the wrong place for your `next` struct member. Instead of

```
struct *node next;
```

it should be

```
struct node *next;
```

And you've got a typo in your main function, too, which causes the `initialization makes pointer from integer` warning. You've typed

```
struct node* header = primeFactor(600851475143);
```

but your function's name is `primeFactors`, plural, so it should be

```
struct node* header = primeFactors(600851475143);
```

You're also using the wrong data type as the parameter to your `primeFactors` function. A signed 32-bit integer can't store a value as large as 600851475143, so you're overflowing it when you assign the value. Assuming the system you're working on supports it, use `uint64_t` or `unsigned long long` instead `int`, and "%llu" as the `printf` format.

Answer (score 3):

Misplaced the `*` in the `struct node` definition. Should be `struct node* next;`

Answer (score 3):

`struct *node next;` should be `struct node * next;`

Answer (score 3):

```
  struct *node next;
```

should be

```
 struct node *next;
```